# Why my Keras model is not loading through all 5 epochs as specified?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
train_length = 972
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
history = model.fit(datagenerator.flow(x_train,y_train, batch_size = 32) ,
                   steps_per_epoch = 30 , epochs = 5, validation_data = datagenerator.flow(x_test, y_test))
```

I will also provide the construction of the model itself below.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, TensorBoard
from keras import optimizers, losses, activations, models
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Dense, Input, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Concatenate
from keras import applications
input_shape = (128,128, 3)

base_model = keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', 
                                include_top=False, 
                                input_shape=(128,128,3))
base_model.trainable = False

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
x= BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Dropout(0.3)(x)
x= Dense(64,activation='relu')(x)
x= BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Dropout(0.3)(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model=Sequential()
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='RMSprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am not sure how to implement validation steps, which I heard is a solution, but I get errors when I do so. How can I edit my code such that it goes through all 5 epochs instead of halting after just one? I will post an image of what it looks like after I run it.
Here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZzQx.jpg

Comment: please show output printed by model.fit. If you leave steps_per_epoch and validation_steps as None model,fit will determine the proper values internally.

Comment: When getting rid of steps per epoch, the code proceeds to run forever.

Comment: strange I run it that way all the time but then I am using flow_from_directory not flow so perhaps it behaves differently. none of these setting should prevent you from running all 5 epochs. Do you get a warning message?

Comment: I tried using flow_from_directory, but i got the following error message [link](https://imgur.com/el4vZc3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way to determine the batch_size and steps.

```
length=len(x_train)
b_max= 80 # set this based on  how much your  memory can hold
batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and 
                  length/n<=b_max],reverse=True)[0] 
steps=int(length/batch_size)
```

do the same with x_test to get the validation batch size and validation steps.
For example if length=972 and b_max=80 then result is batch_size=54 and steps=18
if you set b_max=40 you get batch size=36 and steps=27.
These values ensure you got through your training set or validation exactly once per epoch. Note if length is a prime number, batch_size=1 and steps=length

Comment: your model has 2 classes (dense(2) but your imageDataGenerator input  has 4 classes. That is what cause the error